# How to install with separate home partition (home partition already created in previous installation)?

Tags: installation, partitioning, home-directory

I have Ubuntu 10.10 install on my system with /boot, swap, /root and /home partition. I wish to install 11.10 in my system. In the installation screen The options were:
1 - Erase Ubuntu 11.04 and reinstall
2 - Upgrade Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10
3 - Erase everything and reinstall
4 - Something else

Which option should I choose to get benefited ? If I choose the last option should I have to mark the /home partition and If I hadn't choose it what should I do  now?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would pick option 4, choose the same partition setup you have, but make sure your /home partition is NOT selected in the check box next to 'format'. Hope someone else can give you a more definitive answer, and obviously make a backup of /home regardless.

Comment: While someone ought to test in order to give you an answer, I have used the upgrade option (No. 2) with a separate /home partition for the past couple of releases now, and it has always worked fine for me.

Comment: My experience with option 2 was rather disappointing. It created a new `/home` and converted my primary partitions to logical instead of reusing the existing ones. Definitely go for option 4, and be careful with formatting.

Answer (score 5):

You Select "Something Else." I have just converted my 11.04 to 11.10. And I did not lose any data or settings.

When the partition manager opens, you select each partition in turn and click Change and then mark those same partitions with the same mount points as they have now but you do **not**, I repeat do **not**, mark the /home partition to be formatted. You can mark / and /boot ( if you have one ) to be formatted. This will clear out completely any old files that may conflict with the new install.

In this way the relevant parts of Ubuntu will be installed into / and /boot but the /home partition will not be touched.

You will need to re-install any programs that you installed since 10.10 was installed but they will detect their configuration files in /home as will the default programs for the install.

May I give you some advice? Before you install backup Evolution and Firefox and install Thunderbird and import your Evolution settings/emails into Thunderbird. Do this because Thunderbird is the default email client and not Evolution. So, if you have already converted to Thunderbird you will have email from the beginning without having to install Evolution. Unless you prefer Evolution.

Backup everything just in case.

Regards.

Comment: Cleaned up your answer a bit: the root is just /, /root is the home directory of the root user.  Also most people don't have or need a /boot partition.

Comment: Thank for suggestion. I have installed 11.10 with option 4 and marked /boot as /boot, / as / and /home as /home and I get what I desire. Every thing was fine.